# Reactive Extension (Rx) tutorial that is up to date

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I am quite interested in Reactive Extensions but I cannot find an up to date tutorial. I started with [Curing the asynchronous blues with the Reactive Extensions for .NET](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=208528)  but it is out of date. I can figure out some changes but I could not get many examples working.

I found many articles on the web, mainly from 2009,2010 but they are also incompatible with the current release. I am especially interested in using Rx with Windows Phone and WebClient:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

var o = Observable.FromEvent<DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(wc, "DownloadStringCompleted").Select(newString => newString.EventArgs.Result);

// Subscribe to the observable, and set the label text
o.Subscribe(s => myLabel.Text = s);

// Start the download
wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.data.com/service"));
```

Do not work anymore and replacing `FromEvent` with `FromEventPattern` is not enough.

Can somebody point me to an up to date resource?

Comment: I'm having similar issues - the PDF seems to be very out of date, with many methods no longer existing, which is a shame.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

When learning Rx the first thing is to understand the philosophy behind IObservable and how it's push based nature compares with IEnumerable. I suggest the following one for a good explanation: [A[nother] Simpler Tutorial for Reactive Extensions](http://web.archive.org/web/20140204230626/http://notabeta.com/2011/01/07/another-simpler-tutorial-rx/)

Lee Campbell has nice series explaining the api and when to use them. <s>He also tries to keep it up to date with latest releases: [Reactive Extensions for .NET an Introduction](http://leecampbell.blogspot.com/2010/08/reactive-extensions-for-net.html)</s>
 The series is now available as a book at [Introduction to Rx](http://www.introtorx.com/)

By the way, I have also written a blog post about solving real life problem with rx: [Using Reactive Extensions for Streaming Data from Database](http://www.giorgi.dev/reactive-extensions/using-reactive-extensions-for-streaming-data-from-database/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Reactive Extensions for .NET an Introduction seems really useful, thanks.

Comment: Note, Lee just published an expanded set of tutorials as an ebook - it's on his site.

Comment: The book is available here: http://www.introtorx.com/, the linked article above says to go there instead.

Answer (score 20):

I found a "learn by doing" project called [Reactive Extensions (Rx) Koans](http://rxkoans.codeplex.com/).
It was last updated in March 2012, so it's fairly up-to-date.

> **Definition of ‘Koan’**  
>   Kōans is a zen word meaning the enlightenment or awakening of a person, usually through a puzzle or riddle. The most common one is “What is the sound of one hand clapping?”

It is made of a series of almost-complete unit tests that you must finish in such a way that they pass. You do this by 'filling in the blanks'.

It's pretty neat, quite easy to complete, and gives valuable insight.

**Oh yeah, and it's made by *[Bart De Smet](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/Default.aspx)* from the Rx team.**

Here's a typical unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DoingInTheMiddle()
{
    var status = new List<String>();
    var daysTillTest = Range.Create(4, 1).ToObservable();
    daysTillTest.Do(d => status.Add(d + "=" + (d == 1 ? "Study Like Mad" : ___)))
                .Subscribe();
    Assert.AreEqual("[4=Party, 3=Party, 2=Party, 1=Study Like Mad]", status.AsString());
}
```

Comment: Codeplex is no more. Someone has kindly [ported the koan to .net 5 and uploaded it to github](https://github.com/ttu/csharp-rx-koans).

Answer (score 16):

By far the best resource that helped me wrap my head around Rx is: 
http://www.introtorx.com/

I'm thinking this happens to a lot of people, but you can't find that site when searching on the keywords "Rx tutorial". Think somebody needs to add some tags to the site!

Comment: That is funny Mr Lee Campbell the author of introtorx :)

Answer (score 5):

Read this online book line by line (every line) and practice. This is good, I did when I started with Rx.

http://www.introtorx.com/