# Getting IObservable<string> object as response to POST request, how can I get the string itself?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I'm using this code snippet to send POST request:

```
public IObservable<string> BeginPost(Uri uri, string postData)
{
    var request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    var fetchRequestStream = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<Stream>(request.BeginGetRequestStream, request.EndGetRequestStream);
    var fetchResponse = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse);
    return fetchRequestStream().SelectMany(stream =>
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream)) writer.Write(postData);
        return fetchResponse();
    }).Select(result =>
    {
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)result;
        string s = "";
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) 
                s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return s;
    });
}
```

I'm new to C# and I don't really understand why do I have to use this `IObservable` interface. I was trying to find any information about it on the internet, but I couldn't.

What I really need is to get reponse from webservice as a `string` and in the example I gave, what I get is `IObservable<string>`. So basically, how can I get my `string` from it?

I know this is a bit silly question, but I would also appreciate any links to sites where I could read more about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have to use an IObservable. I suppose you got this code from someone working with [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx). The idea behind this is, that you subscribe to this "event" and each time the request is made a string is send to you. For more info on Reactive Extensions, see the answers to this question [Reactive Extension (Rx) tutorial that is up to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011369/reactive-extension-rx-tutorial-that-is-up-to-date)

If you do not want to use the Reactive Extensions, I recommend using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/). It is a nice library that also works with Windows Phone and you can find many samples on how to use it.